# CGAL: Refining triangulation with collinear faces

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a 2D triangulation created with `Constrained_triangulation_plus_2`. I am adding many constraints coming from vector data for a geographic region. The problem is later when I create a `Surface_mesh` out of this triangulation, I come up with collinear faces (checking the triangulation faces didn't show collinear faces).

I tried to fix this problem by refining the triangulation using a `Delaunay_mesher_2`:

```
mesher.set_criteria(Criteria(0.125,edge_max_length));
mesher.refine_mesh();
```

This will give me the following runtime exception:

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : n == zone.fh
File       : ../CGAL-4.8/include/CGAL/Mesh_2/Refine_edges.h
Line       : 447
Explanation: 
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at http://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CGAL::Assertion_exception: CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: n == zone.fh
File: ../CGAL-4.8/include/CGAL/Mesh_2/Refine_edges.h
Line: 447
```

I couldn't really understand what is happening in `Refine_edges.h`, though I guess that's something to do with collinear faces. I even tried `mesher.step_by_step_refine_mesh()` function for some number of iterations, but that didn't fix those very small triangles.

Then I tried to remove small triangles from the triangulation, but some of them at least had a constrained edge, so that was not possible too, and I couldn't find a way to modify if an edge is constrained, or even if I do, that would break the closed region of a constraint on my triangulation.
I also tried to simplify triangulation before refining, using a call like `PS::simplify(cdtp, Cost(), Stop(1e-5))`, but that didn't seem to fix the error.

So, my question is how can I modify the triangulation so the `refine_mesh()` won't run into a problem? I'm currently using the `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`. I tried using an exact kernel too, in that case I didn't get that runtime error, but the refine function took forever.

Comment: You should not have collinear faces. How did you create the `Surface_mesh` from the triangulation?

Comment: @sloriot I just iterated the faces using `cdtp.finite_faces_begin()` and `cdtp.finite_faces_end()` and then used `vertex_handle->point()` to get points to insert inside the mesh. I'm not sure, maybe after adding elevation for z, the new 3D triangle becomes collinear, due to floating-point errors.

Comment: if you already use `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` for the 2D triangulation you cannot create collinear triangle, whatever value you choose for z. Could you share the output mesh (in a gist for example)?

Comment: @sloriot Checking the output mesh just after creating, showed no signs of collinear triangles, I only detected some triangles with very small areas (in the order of 1e-15), but not zeros, but later the collinear ones are much much more. Looking at my code, I realized later I need to rotate/scale my input mesh, which looks like where I introduce the errors. So, is there a way to do the transformation without any errors? or is there a way to get rid of small triangles to prevent this?

Comment: trying to refine the mesh might be a good idea.